# Azure N series quota exceeded? How?

Tags: azure

Right, so some time ago I requested access to the N Series instances with gpu.

Don`t know what happened but when I try to create a new W. 2012 R2 datacenter server I have the option to create an NC6. I configure the whole thing and at the end it tells me I have ZERO cores available.

I have 2 types of subscription. Pay as You Go and Free Trial. Pay as You Go has a remaining of 10 cores and I have no other instance created.

How can I fix this? I really need around 30-40 hours time of one of those instances for an important project of mine that requires intense 3D capabilities.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a service/support question, not a programming question. The type of thing that's solvable via billing ticket requesting additional resources (billing support is free).

Comment: No, you don`t understand. I have 10 cores of usage, and I can create any other instance BESIDES the N series.

Comment: If I try to send a ticket it already tells me I have 10 cores that I can use. But the N series the instances with a graphic unit don`t work. When creating them it tells me I have 0 cores that I can use for this.

Comment: I don't think *you* understand: This is a service support question. Also, it's for a *preview* service that you must sign up for, and then wait for a response that tells you about your access granted. There is *nothing* that can be solved here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, didn`t mean to sound rude to you. That was not my intention and it does seem you felt offended.

Comment: I understand now, I signed up for the preview, got a few emails, nothing on the fact that I have access to the N series indeed so that`s maybe the problem as you said. 

I understand there is nothing that can be done here I just thought some other people are experiencing the same thing and that it might be a problem, but it seems it`s just the fact that I have probably not been granted access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to signup for this preview on http://gpu.azure.com/